# IOException was unhandled C#

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        File.Create("Script.txt");
        execute();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

 static void execute()
    {
        if (File.Exists("Script.txt"))
        {
            string[] codex = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Script.txt");
            foreach (string i in codex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ", i);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The path does not exists.");
        }
    }
```

I tried this code but I get this error.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Please show the full exception _message_ (which tells you _what_ went wrong) and the **stack trace** (which tells you _where_ it went wrong: `File.Create` or `File.ReadAllLInes`).

Comment: `try and catch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
File.Create("Script.txt");
```

into

```
using (File.Create("Script.txt")) {}
```

Stream would be closed and your

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Script.txt");
```

will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The function File.Create(string filename) returns an open stream.

You should write something inside before reading.
Then you have to close the stream before calling File.ReadAllLines.

Documentation can be found here: (File.Create)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx

Documentation can be found here: (File.ReadAllLines)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

`File.Create` will acquire an exclusive lock on the file that it just created.

No other callers will be able to access the file until the lock is released by calling `.Dispose()` or `.Close()`

However I would suggest you use a `StreamWriter` and wrap it inside a using for your case

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("file name"))
{
    //do something
}
```